# how to trim trailing spaces from every columns in all tables in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Am struggled in this task that is I need to *trim* all the *trailing spaces* from each and every *columns* of all *tables* in my `PostgreSQL Database`.

I've

```
update tbl_sale set product=trim(product) where product LIKE '% '
```

this will `TRIM` the `product` *column* in *table* `tbl_sale`.

---

In my *database* *137 tables* are there,So is it possible to `TRIM` all the *columns* in my *databases* if a it have *trailing space* ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following *query* will return all *tables* and their  *columns* that may or may not have *trailing spaces*.

**NOTE** : I'm assuming that all tables have `tbl_` prefix.

```
 select 
     table_name,COLUMN_NAME
 from 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 where 
     table_name LIKE 'tbl_%' and (data_type='text' or data_type='character varying')
```

to get the `UPDATE` *query* for all tables use the following *select*

```
select 
       'UPDATE '||quote_ident(c.table_name)||' SET '||c.COLUMN_NAME||'=TRIM('||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||')  
        WHERE '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||' ILIKE ''% '' ' as script
from (
        select 
           table_name,COLUMN_NAME
        from 
           INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        where 
           table_name LIKE 'tbl_%' and (data_type='text' or data_type='character varying')
     ) c
```

This will *return* rows like 
`update tbl_sale set product=trim(product) where product LIKE '% '` to update all *columns* in all *tables*.

---

Finally,

Use this method to *update* all *columns* in a `database` that having *trailing space*.

```
do $$
declare
    selectrow record;
begin
for selectrow in
select 
       'UPDATE '||quote_ident(c.table_name)||' SET '||c.COLUMN_NAME||'=TRIM('||c.COLUMN_NAME||')  WHERE '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||' ILIKE ''% '' ' as script
from (
       select 
          table_name,COLUMN_NAME
       from 
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       where 
          table_name LIKE 'tbl_%'  and (data_type='text' or data_type='character varying' )
     ) c
loop
execute selectrow.script;
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Wrap the above method into a `Function`, So that it is more convenient to use future

```
create function rm_trail_spaces() returns void as 
   $$

    declare
        selectrow record;
    begin
    for selectrow in
    select 
           'UPDATE '||quote_ident(c.table_name)||' SET '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||'=TRIM('||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||')  WHERE '||quote_ident(c.COLUMN_NAME)||' ILIKE ''% '' ' as script
    from (
           select 
              table_name,COLUMN_NAME
           from 
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
           where 
              table_name LIKE 'tbl_%'  and (data_type='text' or data_type='character varying' )
         ) c
    loop
    execute selectrow.script;
    end loop;
    end;
  $$
  language plpgsql
```

usage: `SELECT rm_trail_spaces()`

Comment: ohh..I really appreciate your effort to find an answer for my _question_ and well explained

Comment: Note: You could use `quote_ident(...)` on the table- and column names.